# Contextual mix of lining and old-style numbers

Tags: fonts, best-practices, oldstylenums

I am developing a class that fits the needs of both academics and non-academics; the latter often need to write highly legible numbers that are not math (they will be prices, reference numbers, dates, etc.).

For this purpose, the choice of fonts is very limited – we need a free, old-style font with as many alphabets as we can get, including at least all of Latin Extended and Greek (some medieval alphabets are a good point). It also needs to be reasonably XeLaTeX and copy-paste friendly. I settled for Junicode (though I am open to suggestions).

The problem is that Junicode has an old-style `1` that looks just like a lowercase `I`, hence it is suitable for academics and general page designs, but not for the contents of non-academic documents. The developer does not seem to have been active lately – we asked for an alternate old-style `1`. My current solution is to create an option (academic vs. others) that affects the old-style numbers feature for the entire document.

What are other solutions that would allow me to switch numbers in a clean and subtle (contextual) way?

- By using a different set of numbers throughout the documents (I have tried several solutions that change the `catcodes`, but then footnotes failed to superscript). *See the code below.*
- By switching to lining numbers on non-academic documents but only for text that is directly inputed by the user after `\begin{document}` (not class-defined macros, unless specified).
- By using a specific command that changes the font (this one is easy to implement, so the question is: what would be a wise, ergonomic and user-friendly way to do it, otherwise the extra hassle for the end-user is not worth it).
- I am not into tweaking the font itself, since the idea is to release the class (but another compatible font would be ok).
- Or anything else you can think of.

---

My first attempt was as follows. It works just fine, except `\textsuperscript` numbers are set at normal size on the baseline (*e.g.* `\footnotemark`) — and I suspect this hack would cause other problems when used in a long or complex document that includes bibliographies, indexes, etc.

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Junicode}

\newfontfamily\numbersfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Georgia}

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`0=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`1=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`2=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`3=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`4=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`5=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`6=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`7=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`8=\charnumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`9=\charnumbers

\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \charnumbers = {\begingroup\numbersfont}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \charnumbers = {\begingroup\numbersfont}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \charnumbers 0 = {\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \charnumbers 255 = {\endgroup}
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this issue or provide an alternative solution that does not require too much from the end-user? (As explained above.)

Comment: Why are oldtyle numbers only suitable for academics?  I suspect most 'non-academics' would not be thrown by an oldstyle number 1.  I'd recommend instead providing a class option that allows the user to pick whether oldstyle numbers should be used or not rather than mixing oldstyle and non-oldstyle numbers; you can add the 'specific command' too for the special cases that are sure to arise.  And look at `etoolbox`'s `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment` for hooking into various environments.

Comment: I personally do not mind old-style figures anywhere, but in legal documents we need `1` to look like a `1` no matter what. Hence the question – I would like to keep using OSF as much as possible because they are suitable, but I need to find a proper way to either switch fonts or replace them by lining figures when needed. The goal is to *avoid* forcing users to use tons of environments or commands just to get what they want – or to find an implementation that is at least sensible (e.g. it could function as some kind of "semi-math" mode).

Comment: What about the STIX fonts? They have wide coverage. (But I haven't checked the appearance of figures.) Deja Vu also has wide coverage.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the suggestion. If we could reasonably use "réales" such as those (Times New Roman sort of style), we definitely would have a wider range of possible fonts – even modern fonts would be easy (just use Latin Modern). Trust me, I have envisioned a lot of possibilities, and Junicode mostly stood out because it is old fashioned while being highly legible, and (over all other such existing fonts) it can be replaced with Adobe Garamond Pro pretty much without changing line breaks (and there are lots of people who do use Adobe's fonts). So I really am looking for a LaTeX solution.

Comment: Do you mean you want OSF for all numbers but 1? (Surely not....)  THe point about the environments was simply that you can, in the class(!), make it so that various environments do the right thing automatically: it would not be left to the users.  Anyway, with `fontspec` it would be easy to provide a 'user level' switch for numbers (which you could also use in environments as needed).  One other consideration: what happens when users load their own fonts?

Comment: @jon Thanks for your comments. As suggested in my post, the best option would be to use OSF everywhere, but switch them for another font's OSF digits (but I had problems with footnotes). Second best would be to selectively use lining figures in certain contexts (e.g. `\AtBeginDocument` but without affecting previously defined macros). We do not use environments much, and have very few commands except for sectioning and references (the public is non-TeX-savvy). Manually changing the font is more of a "best-practices" question – what kind of implementation would be efficient and unobtrusive?

Comment: I see, I think: so, in essence, use (say) Junicode but with a different number set that doesn't have the ambiguous '1'..?

Comment: That was my first attempt, but modifying the catcodes for every number (in XeLaTeX) screwed up the superscripts used in footnotes. So a fix for this would be a great solution. I will edit my question adding the code.

Comment: Have you tried the EB Garamond? The OTF can be downloaded here: http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/. With RawFeature=+cv11 you can have the 1 (not I) in OSF

Comment: @Ludenticus Eb Garamond was my first choice of font, but it was not very XeLaTeX compatible (impossible to copy-paste your final output and still be able to read it). I will have to give it another try if the author/adapter solves this issue. Additionally, I had some unresolved issues concerning guillemets with the author (they are far too large for non-historical texts, but he did not want to create an OTF variant).

Comment: Would you elaborate what are the problems you find with the copy-paste operation?

Comment: @Ludenticus Small-caps are not probably encoded properly, they come out as private use characters on copy-pasting. Except in my language, we write all last names in small caps, so copy-pasting any academic article quickly becomes a nightmare.

Comment: I think you must take another look, because I can cut/paste small caps of EB Garamond (at least with Evince). On the other hand, it might be easier to find a «general purpose» font (as the one you require) and combine it a polytonic greek font.

Comment: I will try. Admittedly, I did not try again with each and every later version of EB Garamond, which is still evolving quite lot (contrary to Junicode, which is pretty much stable). — One difficulty not mentioned in the original post, the font needs to have proper kerning for French (most fonts have apostrophes set for English, and French requires more kerning because the apostrophe separates words instead of marking elision).

Comment: Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) instead of 255.